# Separate DefinePlugin constants per chunk / entry

Tags: webpack

Is there a way to effectively inject `DefinePlugin` constants that are different per chunk / entry?

It doesn't look like there's a way to specify `chunks` on DefinePlugin like there is on, say, `HtmlWebpackPlugin`.

Comment: Hi, did you find any solution ?

Comment: @SamuelMaisonneuve: I didn't find a solution, I ended up just working around my issue. Don't recall exactly how, sorry.

Comment: Ok thanks for your answer

Answer (score 0):

What if you created object that would map your named chunks with values for `DefinePlugin`?

```js
const CHUNK_NAMES = {
  MAIN: 'main',
  VENDOR: 'vendor',
}

const CONSTANTS = {
  [CHUNK_NAMES.MAIN]: {
     env: '...',
  },
  [CHUNK_NAMES.VENDOR]: {} // you get the idea
}
```

Placing it in separate file would make for cleaner approach, perhaps putting constants in different `.json` files that you could combine or even use spread operator to avoid copying could work well.